# Using for-loop to overwrite values for a variable

Tags: r, function, for-loop

So I'm new to R and have to write a function with a for-loop that can handle the following all at once:

```
year[grep("1 =", x$Year)] <- "1"
year[grep("2 =", x$Year)] <- "2"
year[grep("3 =", x$Year)] <- "3"
year[grep("4 =", x$Year)] <- "4"
year[grep("Beyond", x$Year)] <- "4+"
```

I was given this to start with:

```
relabelCharVector <- function(z, search, repl) {
```

And I'm fairly certain the for-loop starts like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(search)) {
```

but I'm not sure what to do with the body of the for-loop, other than it should involve `grep()`.

I imagine there are probably easier ways to do this, but for the purposes of this question, for-loops are preferred.

Comment: can you give more details about what z (data frame?), search (vector?), and repl (vector?) are? try `z[grep(search[i], z)] <- repl[i]` or similar in the loop and `return(z)` outside of the loop

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did. It worked, so thanks.